# Sliding Sidebars, Disappearing Buttons, Conditional Statements

Tags: jquery, css, tumblr, conditional-statements

Firstly, here's the theme I'm working on, if that helps. ([x](http://riskydbusiness.tumblr.com))

I'm trying to make the sidebars collapsible. Well, with what I've gotten with this jQuery, it does collapse fine. It's the arrow buttons that are stumping me.

Here's the code I have; it only affects the left sidebar, I figured I could just copy this and change some classes and IDs for the right one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#leftside').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#leftbutton.contained').fadeIn() 
    });
    if($('#leftside').is(':visible')) {
        $('#leftside').mouseleave(function(){
            $('#leftbutton.contained').delay(800).fadeOut() 
        });
    }
    $('#leftbutton').click(function(){
        $('#leftside').toggle("slide");
        $('#leftbutton').toggleClass("contained");
    }); 
});
```

I wanted the button to appear when the proper sidebar is hovered over, and to disappear when you leave it. That works fine, thankfully! But, once the sidebar disappears when it's collapsed, so does the button.

The class "contained" just has a display of none, by the way. My theory was that if I attached that class to the button and toggled it, the button would then stay visible after the sidebar goes. Unfortunately, that's not the case.

What am I doing wrong?

(Also, on the horizon: after the sidebar slides in, I want the arrow to, while visible, slide over out of the main area and hang out on the edge of the ".house" div, in case the viewer wants the sidebars back. I have just the faintest idea how to accomplish that, and that's to animate the change from the left and right attributes. Once the sidebar is toggled back, it goes back to hiding and revealing when the mouse leaves and enters, respectively. If you have any tips or the answer for this inevitable problem, I'd appreciate that too!)

**EDIT:** The code suggested to me still doesn't work! I tried to maybe do another conditional, and that still doesn't work. This is ridiculous.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('#leftside').is(:visible)) {
    $('#leftside').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#leftbutton.contained').fadeIn() 
    });
    $('#leftside').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#leftbutton.contained').delay(800).fadeOut() 
    });
    } else { $('#leftbutton').css("display:block") }
```

I know this is probably obvious to a more seasoned coder, but I'm stumped and a little frustrated.

Comment: I believe the -1 rating (not mine) is because it's a bit difficult to imagine what you want to do exactly. Maybe a small drawing would make it clear ?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery isn't doing some logic like in embedded systems. Your `if($('#leftside').is(':visible')) {` Is only executed once when the document is loaded. Then, whatever happens after isn't taken into account.

I think I understood what your intent is though. I think instead of making the sidebar disappear completely, you can shrink it to 1-2 pixel, so that when the user moves his mouse to the edge of the screen, you can trigger onhover events to show the arrows where you want.

var expanded= true

```
$('#leftside').hover(function(){ 
    //MouseEnter
    $('#leftbutton.contained').fadeIn()
}, function(){
    //Mouse leaves
    $('#leftbutton.contained').delay(800).fadeOut() 
}

$('#leftbutton').click(function(){
    if (expanded){
        $('#leftside').css("width", 2)
        // Reposition #leftButton where you want when the left menu is NOT visible
    } else{
        $('#leftside').css("width", DEFAULT_VALUE)
        // Reposition #leftButton when the left menu IS visible
    }
    $('#leftbutton').toggleClass("contained");
    expanded = !expanded
});
```

Comment: Sorry! I tried this code and it won't work still. I inspected the element and it appears that the arrow really wants to stick to "display:none" after the sidebar disappears. The class that is supposed to be what keeps it invisible DOES successfully toggle off. What gives?